# Proof for an algebraic inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the following expression 
$$f(a,b) = a^{4/3} - \left(\frac{1+3a}{4 - b}\right) \left(\frac{a - 1}{b}\right)^{1/3}.$$

Is $f(a,b) < 1$ for $a > 1$, $ b \in (0,1)?$
If not, could you give a counter example?

My attempt at the problem:

For $b \in (0,1)$, $$f(a,b) \leq a^{4/3} - \left( \frac{1+3a}{3} \right) (a - 1)^{1/3} = g(a),$$
since $(4 - b)b^{1/3} \leq 3,$ for $b \in (0,1)$.

Therefore, if I could prove $g(a) < 1$ for $a > 1$ or equivalently $h(c) < 1$ for $c  > 0$, where
$$h(c) = (1 + c)^{4/3} - c^{4/3} - \frac{4c^{1/3}}{3},$$
it would prove my result.
When I plotted the above function in Matlab, I see $h(c) < 1$, however I was not able to prove it.

Edit: A more general result seems to be true (from plots, though I could not prove the result). If I set $g(x) = (1 + x)^k - x^k$, then for $k \in (1,2)$ and $c >0$ $$ kx^{k-1} < g(x) < 1 + kx^{k-1}.$$ I am interested in the upper bound, the lower bound can be proved using Taylor series expansion.

Comment: Did you try graphing it in some graphing package like Maple?

Comment: Yes I did it in Matlab and it seemed correct.

Comment: Through a few plots, a more general result seems to be correct. Though I am not able to prove that:  Let $h(c) = (1 + c)^k - c^k$, if $k \in (1,2)$, we have $$ k c^{k-1} < h(c) < 1 + k c^{k-1}.$$ The lower bound can be proved by Taylor's series expansion. I could not get the upper bound though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\alpha \in (1,2)$ consider the function
$$ \tag{1} 
y \mapsto (1+y)^\alpha - y^\alpha, \quad y \geq 0. 
$$
Since the second derivative of this function is 
$$
\alpha (\alpha -1) \bigl( (1+y)^{\alpha-2} - y^{\alpha-2} \bigr) \lt 0 \quad  \text{for all} \quad y \gt 0,
$$
the function in (1) is concave down. As the tangent line of the function in (1) at $(0,1)$ is $y \mapsto \alpha y + 1,$ we have 
$$ \tag{2}
(1+y)^\alpha - y^\alpha \lt \alpha y + 1 \quad  \text{for all} \quad y \gt 0.
$$
Substituting $1/x$ for $y$ in (2) we get 
$$
\frac{(x+1)^\alpha}{x^\alpha} - \frac{1}{x^\alpha} \lt \frac{\alpha}{x} + 1 \quad  \text{for all} \quad x \gt 0.
$$
Multiplying by $x^\alpha > 0$ we get 
$$
(x+1)^\alpha - 1  \lt \alpha x^{\alpha-1} + x^\alpha \quad  \text{for all} \quad x \gt 0,
$$
and hence 
$$
(x+1)^\alpha - x^\alpha  \lt 1 + \alpha  x^{\alpha-1} \quad  \text{for all} \quad x \gt 0. 
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer :)